# Eclipse Backup - how to get back to a specific date

Tags: eclipse, backup

I've heard that Eclipse has a few fancy backup options.
I've been working on an Eclipse project (using Pydev), and I would like to somehow switch back to the way the project was a few days ago. Is there such an option?

What I've found till now was only the backup files (specifically what I changed and when), but I don't know how to get to the exact state the whole project was on a specific date.

Please help :-(

Comment: Eclipse only has `Replace With > Local History` for individual files (and `Restore from Local History` for deleted files). By default the local history is only kept for a few days. For anything more complex you should start using one of the many source control systems supported by Eclipse (SVN, Git, ....)

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. Maybe you could post that as an answer (the `replace with local history` thing), so if no one else comes up with a miraculous suggestion or something, I could accept it.

Comment: Added a slightly expanded answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse has `Replace With > Local History` for individual files (and `Restore from Local History` for deleted files).

By default the local history is only kept for a few days, you can configure this in `Preferences > Workspace > Local History`.

For anything more complex you can use one of the many source control systems supported by Eclipse such as SVN or Git. This is worth doing just for the extra backup and does not require a separate server.